# Why would a program run when launch from windows but not the command prompt?

Tags: c++, vba, command-prompt

I wrote a small C++ program in VS2k8. When I launch it from windows (double click the exe file) it runs fine. When I go to the command prompt and try to run it it will hang and eventually crash. I've created test programs with simple outputs that work fine both ways.

Is there something I'm missing? I'm relatively new to programming. I'm trying to launch this program using the VBA shell command but it produces the same outcome as the command prompt.

The funny thing is it was working fine at first until I went in to change the value of a constant variable and rebuilt it (I didn't think that had anything to do with it but I changed it back with no success). No settings where changed.

Edit: I've name it time.exe and than copies.exe (when I tried copying and pasting the code into a new project). The actual code is about 250 lines, not sure what part of it would be causing the issue. It opens a .csv file, loads the information into vectors, and then compares the vectors to each other (adding something to the end of it if it meets certain conditions). It than outputs the file to another .csv file.

Comment: Code please.  At least a simple example that recreates your issue.

Comment: What did you call it? Are you sure you aren't running some windowsor shell command with the same name?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Try running the app from the cmd prompt under windbg and see where it's failing. Does it work when you F5 in VisualStudio?

Comment: Does the code do any error checking?  What happens if the .csv file is not there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Might suggest that the current directory on start up is different and this is causing your issue as you make some assumptions about the current path or drive?

Comment: Agreed.  Try using absolute path when loading your .csv file and see if it works then.

Comment: That was it! Can't believe it was something so dumb. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @0geek always the easy things... :)